# Rundeck - execute script file in directory

Tags: rundeck

I would like to use the "Script File" step in a Job to execute some bash scripts.

I'm trying to set up a *scripts* directory for a project, in order to keep all my script files together.

In some cases, script file A might be dependent on script file B, e.g.:

```
 # -- file ScriptA.sh
 #! /bin/env bash
 # 
 # set up variables
 . ScriptB.sh
 #
```

How can I tell Rundeck about ScriptA.sh, and all its dependent scripts?  How can I get them copied to the (temp) directory where they will be executed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rundeck does not handle a script file dependencies, you need to set them up in order to successfully run your script file.

**Note:** if your script files are not in the same folder, then you should explicitly call them with an absolute path and execute them with the `sh` command.

Example:

```
 # -- file scriptA.sh
 #! /bin/env bash
 # 
 # set up variables
 sh /path/to/script/scriptB.sh
 #
```